# If $x + \mathrm{Jac}(R)$ is invertible in $R/\mathrm{Jac}(R)$ then $x$ is invertible in $R$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Basically, given any ring $R$ and $x \in R$, I want to prove that if $x + \mathrm{Jac}(R)$ is invertible in $R/\mathrm{Jac}(R)$ then $x$ is invertible in $R$. Where $\mathrm{Jac}(R)$ is the intersection of all right maximal ideals of $R$.

I know that if $x + \mathrm{Jac}(R)$ is invertible then $x \notin \mathrm{Jac}(R)$, therefore I think that $x \notin M$, for any maximal ideal $M$ (since $\mathrm{Jac}(R) \subset M$, for any $M$).

So, we must have $xR = R$ (otherwise $xR$ would be contained in some maximal ideal $M$, I think). So, there is some $y \in R$, such that $xy = 1$. If I do the same for $yR = R$ then $yz = 1$, so $x = xyz = z$ and the result follows. I also think that since $\mathrm{Jac}(R)$ also coincides with the intersection of all left maximal ideals I could simply do $Rx = R$, but I’m not sure if I could to this.

I’m not quite sure if the way I conclude some things is correct or if I’m missing some important step.

Comment: It seems you haven't even tried using the definition of "invertible" and the quotient ring. Write down what the assumption is telling you, just by compiling the definitions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have the assumption that $x + \mathrm{Jac}(R)$ is invertible in $R / \mathrm{Jac}(R)$. This means, by definition of invertibility and the quotient ring construction, that there is some $y \in R$ such that $xy - 1 \in \mathrm{Jac}(R)$ and $ yx - 1 \in \mathrm{Jac}(R)$. Now we have the following explicit description of the Jacobson radical: $\mathrm{Jac}(R) = \{r \in R : \forall s \in R ~ (1 - rs \in R^{\times})\}$. In particular, for all $r \in \mathrm{Jac}(R)$ we have $1 + r \in R^{\times}$. In our situation, this yields that $xy$ and $yx$ are invertible. Then $x$ is left- and right-invertible, hence invertible.

Comment: @downvoting person: What should I improve or change?

Comment: +1 yup, it is just this straightforward.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Thank you!